# What is the maximum amount of characters for an ASP.NET textbox with MultiLine TextMode enabled?

Tags: asp.net

I know that the MaxLength property doesn't apply to System.Web.UI.WebControls.Textbox control in MultiLine mode. But what is the maximum amount of characters I can type in the textbox?

It seems to be 1000 characters, but I can't find this documented anywhere.

I am not asking on how to limit the number of characters in the textbox control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no upper limit to the number of characters in a WebControls.Textbox in multiline mode. The only limits are total post data from a form and that depends on your web-servers set-up (I presume IIS) which I think is about 2mb by default in IIS but don't quote me on that.

What is happening when you try to type beyond 1000 charatcters?

Comment: Nothing happens after 1000 characters; as in, no matter what you type, no more characters are displayed in the box. This is probably due to a javascript function that counts the number of characters. The script is probably the limiting factor here. I haven't had time to go back to test that hypothesis though. But I'm pretty sure, if I remove that function, the box should allow >1000 characters.

Comment: Yes I would say that sounds like the most likely case, as it certainly isn't out-of-the-box behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the size of input, but if you use `HTTP GET` method to submit, your data will be encoded and appended to the submit URL. URLs, depending on a browser, have limitation of about 2000 characters. Try using `HTTP PUT` to submit the data in which case the payload is added to the HTTP header of the request which has no size limitations. Check `method` property of your `FORM` element.